# MATLAB Function Elements Range

Tags: function, matlab, range

Sorry for the noob question, but I am a beginner in MATLAB. I need to do the following task, but am stuck. "Write a function that takes three arguments x, a, b, where x is a matrix, and a and b are scalars. The function returns the number of elements in x that lie in the interval [a, b]." Here is what I have so far.

```
function y = count(x,a,b);
for value=a:b
    length(value)
end
```

I need to call the function in the command prompt with the following line:

```
count(randn(20, 20), 0, 5)
```

However, I'm not getting anything close to the correct answer. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried to write something like `x<b` (substitute `b` with a number)? Look at the result, this will bring you closer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at, does it involve a nested if statement?

Comment: @ShankarKumar: no, just try `x = randn(5, 5)` and then `x > 1`.

Comment: @DSM: Are you saying to alter the command line? I need to keep that how it is (It was provided to us). I need to alter the code in the last three lines of the first box to fit that command. :(

Comment: @ShankarKumar: we're trying to hint to you how to change the code.  Go to the MATLAB console.  Type `x = rand(5,5)` to make a 5x5 array.  Then type `x > 1` and see what that gives you.  Then think about what you can do with that information.

Comment: Okay, so it returns 1 for the values that are greater than 1, and 0 for the values that are less than 1. So now I need to count the number of values equal to 1?

Comment: @ShankarKumar Spot on! Look into the `sum` function, and remember that it can be applied iteratively, ie `sum(sum(X))`. Ultimately, this question can be solved in one line without any `for` loops. You just need to use the techniques and functions discussed thus far (you may also need to look up logical operators such as `&&` to get the one-liner).

Comment: Thanks everyone, here is my final answer. I didn't put it all in one line so it would be easier to explain. (I will add comments)

function y = count(x,a,b);

new_array = x>a & x<b;      
first_sum = sum(new_array); 
second_sum = sum(first_sum) 
                            
end

Output:

>> count(randn(20, 20), 0, 5)

second_sum =

   201

Comment: You can simplify a bit further by using `sum` only one time, by using the `(:)` syntax to turn the matrix to a vector.  `total_sum = sum(new_array(:))`

Answer (score 3):

As Jonas suggested `nnz` and `sum` are faster options than `numel(find(...))`, with `sum` being the fastest, therefore:

```
function y = count(x,a,b);
y = sum(x(:)>a & x(:)<b);
```